# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\...\hello-world\node_modules\sshpk\bin\CredDB2.CEF'

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm getting the following error when I do `npm install` in my ReactJS App project folder.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Workspace\programs\Casual\ReactJS\hello-world\node_modules\sshpk\bin\CredDB2.CEF
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Workspace\programs\Casual\ReactJS\hello-world\node_modules\sshpk\bin\CredDB2.CEF'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I had started with this project for practice on an Ubuntu machine and I was able to run it there. But now I'm working on a Windows machine. So, I cloned the repo and did an `npm install` ending up with the following error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another question that got a similar error.

[npm install fails in directory encrypted with Dell Encryption software on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49947151/6042824)

This issue was happening because of the Dell Encryption Software installed on my system. `CredDB2.CEF` is a metadata file created and used by the Dell encryption software which was being placed in the project directory causing issues with `npm install`.

> Dell Encryption creates the `CredDB2.CEF` file as metadata about the encryption state, however, the file created in such a matter that is is hidden from the typical file explorer (even when show hidden files is enabled) and can't be opened by applications using the full path of the file.

This has been explained in detail in the question linked above.

**Solution**

- Open Dell Encryption
- Go to `advanced`
- Go to `Customize Settings`
- Go to `General Settings`
- Select `False` in the Customization drop-down for the Feature `Encryption Enabled`
- Click on `Save`

**Screenshot**

[image]